# ObjectOutputStream: Is this secure?

Tags: android, security, objectoutputstream

I am working on an Android application, and I want to submit a username and password. What I am doing at the moment is:

1. create hashvalue for password
2. Connect to authentication-server via HTTP request
3. send username/hash-password via ObjectOutputStream

I do this because it was the only solution I could implement myself with the knowledge I have yet earned.

But of course there is a question I have to worry about: How secure is this? I know, there is no 100% security. But is this a really poor solution, or average?

Comment: Why are you sending password to server ?

Comment: to check if it is correct. the correct password is stored in a mySQL database. and the server I am sending the password to is accessing this database. the database itself can only be accessed by this one server that receives my password.

Comment: Then use md5, it is 100% secure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not safe as the login / password are not encrypted. Things you should to do are:

- Use https instead of http connection for login
- Add salt to your password before hashing it (username as salt is ok)
- Using serialization as the data protocol is not very handy - it
  doesn't provide any additional security, but will be really awful
  when debugging...

Salt:
If two users have this same password they will have also this same hash. This can be easily recovered using rainbow tables (Google for it). To avoid situations like that passwords should be hashed with some salt, so instead of using:

```
hash(password);
```

You should use:

```
hash(salt+password);
```

Where salt can be some quite long random string hard coded in application (protect from rainbow attacks) or just username as it can be easily accessed on server side and application side.

Comment: what do you mean by "add salt"?

yep I guess serialization is not the best way, but it was the only way that i knew :/